# getting first elements undefined using useEffect react

Tags: reactjs, graphql

[image]

Hi I keep getting undefined for the first element then I get full element is there any way to get the element the first time?

```
const [me,{data}]=useMutation(ME_MUTATON)
const User = data?.me

console.log(,User)

console.log("fgf",User?.userName)

useEffect(() => {

    me()

  
}, [me]);
```

(Hi I keep getting undefined for the first element then I get full element is there any way to get the element at the first time? )

Comment: Try remove strict mode in the app.jsx. your error would be not happening in the production version.

Comment: I've tried it but nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't put your data in useEffect like this ?

```js
const [me, { data }] = useMutation(ME_MUTATON);
const [user, setUser] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    me();
}, [me]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(data && data.me && JSON.stringify(data.me) !== JSON.stringify(user)) {
    const User = data.me;
    console.log(User);
    console.log("Username: ", User.username);
    setUser(User);
  }
}, [data]);
```

Comment: the problem in your code is how i can use that User variable outside useEffect

Comment: I updated my code. You can do it by adding a state.

Comment: thanks , itried that but gives me illimite loop rendering

Comment: @amghare I edited my answer once more. Please check it again and see if it solves your proble,.

Comment: Yeah it works thank but why you use useEffect while we can just use if statement without

Comment: useEffect  i mean we can just use if

Comment: Because if you use your if statements outside of the useEffect, you codes in if executes everytime the component renders. But in useEffect, if only triggers when the data changes.